# How to split a string with no spaces into array of integers in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, string, split, kotlin

I need to split a string into an array of integers. I tried this:

```
val string = "1234567"
val numbers = string.split("").map { it.toInt() }
println(numbers.get(1))
```

but the following Exception is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:
>   For input string: ""  at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   net.projecteuler.Problem_008Kt.main(Problem_008.kt:54)

How to convert a string "123456" into array [1,2,3,4,5,6]?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `split("")` approach results in `[, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ]`, i.e. the first and last element can't be formatted into a number.

Actually, [`CharSequence.map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/map.html) is all you need:

```
val numbers = string.map { it.toString().toInt() } //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

With this code, the single characters of the `String` are converted into the corresponding `Int` representation. It results in a `List<Int>` which can be converted to an array like this:

```
string.map { it.toString().toInt() }.toIntArray()
```

Answer (score 7):

You just don't need `split`, but you must also not call `toInt()` on the character directly; this will give you its Unicode value as an integer. You need `Character.getNumericValue()`:

```
val string = "1234567"
val digits = string.map(Character::getNumericValue).toIntArray()
println(digits[1])
```

It prints 2.

Answer (score 4):

Like already stated, using map suffices. I just want to add that you should consider the case that your string does not only contain numbers.

This extension function would take care of that:

```
fun String.toSingleDigitList() = map {
    "$it".toIntOrNull()
}.filterNotNull()
```

Usage:

```
val digits = "31w4159".toSingleDigitList()
```

Result:

> [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9]